# Laravel authentication without email business at all

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I've just learned how to get Laravel create an authentication infrastructure by issuing a command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It works perfectly fine for me, but I want to keep the authentication process as simple as possible, so I want to eliminate everything that has to do with e-mail. Eventually I want users to register and authenticate into the site by entering only username and password. So no e-mail business is needed, no resetting password is needed.

What should be changed in the standard Laravel authentication code to get rid of any e-mail hassle?

I modified the register controller to this:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller {
    use RegistersUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The migration looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But when I try to register nothing happens. No entry appears in the users table. What's wrong?

Comment: Study the current code present in the controllers @ `\App\Http\Controller\Auth` and change what you deem necessary.

Comment: Perhaps something here would help? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-authentication-using-username-instead-of-email or https://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-with-username-instead-of-email/. You're not the first person who would rather user `username` instead of `email` for authentication. You get plenty of results by searching "Laravel Auth with username instead of email".

Comment: Please stop editing with `>` at the start of every line. That's for blockquotes. Code is 4 spaces of indentation.

Comment: Thanks guys! Finally it works! One more question: what is that supposed to be for in the LoginController:

      public function username() {
           return 'username';
        }